# WS-Security: Differing namespaces for X509 certificates in BinarySecurityToken ValueType and EncodingType

Tags: soap, xml-namespaces, ws-security

I'm currently writing a client that consumes a soap sercvice, and noticed something strange in the SOAP calls from the client we're writing compared to the examples I have from the vendor of the web service.

For the `ValueType` attribute of the `BinarySecurityToken`, it is using `http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3` as the type, whereas my examples use `wsse:X509v3`, where wsse is defined as `http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd`.

From a fair amount of internet research these namespaces seem to be used about equally, and I suspect that they are equivalent, but still wonder if there is a difference and why there are two namepsaces.

Similarly for `EncodingType`, you can use `wsse:Base64Binary` or

```
http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through both the [WSS X509 Token Profile 1.0](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0.pdf) and [WSS X509 Token Profile 1.1](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-os-x509TokenProfile.pdf) specifications. It seems both values for the ValueType are correct. But "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0" is not a namespace. It is a URI defined for the specification [Line 171 of spec 1.0 and Line 158 of spec 1.1]. Both specifications use the WSSE, that is http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd as the namespace.

So the my conclusion is ValueType="wsse:x509v3" (spec 1.0 line 308) is equivalent to ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" (spec 1.1 line 340)

Comment: thanks, This is what I suspected but thanks for confirming in the specifications. Marked your post as answer